# Display "Thank you" message in html on click of button using AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, forms, message, display

I'm trying to complete an email submission form.

I want to show a thank you message when form is submitted (when submit button is clicked)

This is my current code in index.html fie

I don't want window alert like this

[image: window.alert]

I want to hide email box and subscribe button by displaying "Thank you" message.

```js
function call_mailm() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://google.com/form/" + $("#name").val(),
    success: function(result) {
      alert("Mail sent successfully");

    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("There is some problem with mail");
    }
  });
  return false;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Begin  Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

  <form>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="email" class="required email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" style="font-size:15pt;height:38px;width:350px;font- family:Century Gothic;">

    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
      <input type="text" name="b_438e8df85b7f9df7fce94287a_013c74a5bc" tabindex="-1" value="">
    </div>
    <button onclick="return call_mailm()" value="Submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="background-color: rgba(14,46,71,1);border: 1px solid #0E2E47;width:150px;height:37px;font-family: ‘Palatino Linotype’, ‘Book Antiqua’, Palatino, serif;font-size:24px;color:white;">Subscribe</button>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="success" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

inside of  tag like this

```
<div id="success">
Congrats! <br>
 Thank you for subscribing
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('#someElement').text('Thank you')` ?

Comment: no i want display message in <div>

Comment: Then display it in the `div`.  Have you tried anything at all?  There are plenty of introductory jQuery tutorials and examples which show how to write to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new div with a thank you message and delete/hide the form. Simplest example:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://google.com/form/"+$("#name").val(), 
    success: function(result){
      $('#mc_embed_signup').html('<div>Thank you!</div>');

    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("There is some problem with mail");
    }
  });
```

Comment: How to add simple email validation to this ajax code please help i'm new to ajax and i didn't find anything useful on web.